# Validating JAX-RS resources and methods (IBM JAX-RS implementation) using bean validation on Websphere Application Server 8.5.5

Tags: jax-rs, websphere, bean-validation, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

I am using IBM JAX-RS implementation to develop my REST APIs. I am looking to include validation of resource method parameters using Bean Validation (annotations) support provided in JAX-RS 2.0. I know that Jersey implementation supports this feature (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html). Is there a similar support available with IBM JAX-RS implementation on WAS 8.5.5? If so could you please direct me to some tutorial on how to accomplish this?

I am specifically looking into enabling and configuring Bean Validation support along with its integration with IBM JAX-RS.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, WebSphere (both traditional and Liberty) will support bean validation with JAX-RS.  But I am not aware of any tutorials.  The code in the Jersey document that you referenced will work with WebSphere's JAX-RS/BV implementation.

To enable JAX-RS and Bean Validation in Liberty, your server.xml must contain the following features:

```
<featureManager>
  <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
  <feature>beanValidation-1.1</feature>
</featureManager>
```

As an alternative, you could include some feature that includes those features (like webProfile-7.0 or javaee-7.0, but that may get you more function than you want).

Then, if you have your application packaged as an EAR or WAR file, you can copy it into your server's dropins directory, start the server and you should be able to run the example (the default HTTP port is 9080).

This link provides additional information about developing and deploying JAX-RS applications in WebSphere Liberty:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_jaxrs.html

Hope this helps,
Andy

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now at least I know bean validation is supported on Websphere and that my effort in trying to get it work won't go waste. I am specifically looking to make this work on traditional WAS . I will try to include the bean validation feature and see how it works. Thanks again! So how do we add this feature on traditional WAS?

Comment: The feature should be enabled out-of-the-box with traditional WAS.  tWAS basically gives you all features - one-size-fits-all approach, while Liberty lets you pick and choose which features you want enabled.